# is it possible to communicates to certain agent in JADE

Tags: java, pug, agent

I wonder is it possible to send communicates to some group of agent,

for exactly I have Cars agents and many Parking agents in the city.

Now I don't know is it possible to send message for only agents

which are near Car agent, for exactly I want achive

Car communication with five nearest agents.

And how achive this in Jade.

I establish that cars-agents and parkings-agents have location as attribute

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the articles about [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).  As it stands now, your question is too broad for us to give a discrete answer, and it needs more focus.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes you can send a message to a set of agents as one message can have several receivers in Jade.
- See this [Jade communication example](https://startjade.gitlab.io/page/tutorial/communication/)
- Regarding the identification of the nearest agents, its up to you to get their names from your environment with a distance measure.